# VueJS loading data from AJAX call and passing it to child components without v-if

Tags: vue.js

I am loading data in root Vue instance using ajax and trying to pass it to child components. And I am getting undefined data. Of course, It is happening becasue of Async nature of ajax call so my question is how to do it without render blocking the child components using v-if. What is best practice to do it.

Here is my demo app - 
https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/jXQeWv?editors=1010

```
Vue.component('child-one',{
  template:'#child-one',
  props:['mydataOne'] 
});

Vue.component('child-two',{
  template:'#child-two',
  props:['mydataTwo'] 
});

let app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    welcome:'Hello World',
    mydata:null
  },
  methods:{
    getdataApi:function(){
      var self = this;
      $.getJSON( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", function( data ) {
        self.mydata = data;
      }); 
    } 
  },
  created:function(){
    this.getdataApi();
  },
  mounted:function(){ 
    this.getdataApi();
    console.log('api data->',this.mydata);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163297/523630

Your `mydataOne` and `mydataTwo` properties should be `mydata-one` and `mydata-two` in component's html snippet, like so:

```
<div :mydata-one="mydata"></div>
```

Here is a working snipet of your code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jwewde?editors=1010

```
Vue.component('child-one',{
  template:'#child-one',
  props:['one'] 
});

Vue.component('child-two',{
  template:'#child-two',
  props:['two']
});

let app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    welcome:'Hello World',
    mydata:null
  },
  methods:{
    getdataApi(){
      $.getJSON( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", (data) => {
        this.mydata = data;
      }); 
    } 
  },
  mounted:function(){ 
    this.getdataApi();
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know what to search on google so eventually I had to post here. Also, I never expected this could be the reason. I thought That's happening because of asyn nature of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about loading JSON data in Vue using axios:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html